# Python script uses json database; is it possible to have multiple instances of the script writing to the file?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

The script has a database.json file that it reads and writes to with every operation it does. It's a simple database, 'two columns' one with text (includes hyphens, numbers, and underscores) and an associated number. There's about 40,000 rows though.

The script as of right now can only work in the database at one instance. I know this because I had two instances running and when I checked the database half of it was missing, so it would seem the script would erase the data from the other script. Long story short I had to rebuild it from a backup, but I have a question:

**Can a Python script access a json database with read and write in multiple instances? or must the script be written with some more complex database functionality?**

Here are some snippets of the code that interacts with the database:

```
def load_database():
    # If file exists load the json as a dict
    if os.path.isfile('database.json'):
        return json.load(open('database.json', 'r'))
    # If file doesn't exist return empty dict because the script hasn't run yet
    else:
        return {}

------

def save_database():
    json.dump(database, open('database.json', 'w'))

------

        self.user_data = self.get_user_data()
        if self.user_data:
            self.user_id = str(self.user_data['id'])
            if self.user_id in database:
                if database[self.user_id] != self.username:
                    main_log.info('User {} changed their username to {}.'.format(database[self.user_id], self.username))
                    os.rename('Users/{}_{}'.format(database[self.user_id], self.user_id), 'Users/{}_{}'.format(self.username, self.user_id))
                    add_username_to_history('Users/{}_{}/'.format(self.username, self.user_id), database[self.user_id])
                    database[self.user_id] = self.username
                else:
                    safe_mkdir('Users/{}_{}'.format(self.username, self.user_id))
            else:
                safe_mkdir('Users/{}_{}'.format(self.username, self.user_id))
                main_log.info('Added {} with ID:{} to the database.'.format(self.username, self.user_id))
                database.update({self.user_id: self.username})

            # Create the user log obj
            self.user_log = Logger('Users/{}_{}/log.log'.format(self.username, self.user_id))
            # Create ID File
            create_id_file('Users/{}_{}/'.format(self.username, self.user_id), self.user_id)
            save_database()
```

There's a few more instances where the database is called, but those give an idea.

The reason I wanted to run multiple instances was to double up the speed on scraping. I already have ThreadPool and even with 200+ threads it's not as fast as it could be by having multiple instances.

Comment: If by multiple instances you mean running several python interpreters then of cause any file including JSON can't be read/written same time from different pythons, they need some way of synchronization.

Comment: One way to synchronize two scripts writing is to have one manager-process that will somehow manage both scripts synchronization. One thing to take into account that just before writing both databases need to be merged by some logic. All child processes may send updated data to main process, that main process may read current database, apply changes by merging and save them.

Comment: How would synchronization work for something like this? Would all the Python instances have to talk to each other and basically not write to the file until the other one is done? That would defeat the purpose of me running multiple instances, which was to double the speed

Comment: Main thing is that you need some logic of merging. Why? Lets imagine that both scripts have read database in the beginning, each created two different sets of data to be updated into database. Then both this scripts need somehow to merge these two data before writing to database. So you need merging logic in main manager process. Also possible to do without manager if to have `.lock` file. Each child in order to merge-in new updates to database acquires `.lock` file, if busy process waits, then after acquisition scripts reads-in current DB, merges updates and writes back.

Comment: I'll tell you about simple case. Lets imagine the case when each script just produces linear list of objects to save, also different scripts produce different object. Then the easiest form of merging for this case would be just to concatenate lists of both scripts, if that is feasible. Each script when it wants to flush data just acquires `.lock` file (creates if not avaialable) or waits until lock is released (deleted), then reads-in database, appends new list of object,writes back,releases the lock(deletes).This is the simplest form of synchronization using file locks,UNIX systems do samely.

Comment: That locking mechanism makes the most sense for my scenario. I will look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a Redis database. This allowed the script to individually write to the database thus allowing multiple instances of the script to be running.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the concept of atomicity.

Since your json file is not too big, one not-ideal-but-workable option could be :

1. When needed to read:  open file, read values into variable(s), close connection i.e. do not keep the json open
2. Repeat the step 1 everytime you need to read the database
3. When needed to write: open file, write values into json, close connection i.e. do not keep the json open
4. Repeat step 2 everytime you need to run any DML

Comment: If the database is big enough to take longer time to read/write, then, as @Arty mentioned, you need synchronisation.